# Exception Value: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: &#x27;products_web:8001&#x27;. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035

Tags: django, docker, nginx

Using docker i have created 3 django projects :- products, orders, email.

supporting technologies :- nginx and postgres.

Here each project work as microservice to work each service as individual unit.

[image: image to show]

I have to get **product details** from **orders service**, for that i used requests pipe line

> orders/src/views.py

```
response = requests.get("http://products_web:8001/products/fetch/?prod_id=%s" % product).json()
```

when i execute, getting response in html format defining error as **Exception Value: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'products_web:8001'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.**

following is the docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'


services:



  products_web:
    build: ./products
    command: bash -c "python3 ./products/manage.py makemigrations && python3 ./products/manage.py migrate && python3 ./products/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - datab
    links:
      - datab

  emails_web:
    build: ./emails
    command: bash -c "python3 ./emails/manage.py makemigrations && python3 ./emails/manage.py migrate && python3 ./emails/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8002:8002"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - datab
    links:
      - datab

  orders_web:
    build: ./orders
    command: bash -c "python3 ./orders/manage.py makemigrations && python3 ./orders/manage.py migrate && python3 ./orders/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8003"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8003:8003"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
       - datab
    links:
      - datab
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true 

  datab:
    image: postgres
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - "8084:80"
    links:
      - products_web
      - orders_web
      - emails_web
    depends_on:
      - products_web
      - orders_web
      - emails_web
```

following is the nginx.conf

```
server {

    listen 8000;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;
    charset utf-8;

    location /api/v1/products {
      rewrite /api/v1/products(.*) /products$1 break;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
      proxy_pass http://products_web:8001;
   }


   location /api/v1/emails {
      rewrite /api/v1/emails(.*) /emails$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://emails_web:8002;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }


   location /api/v1/orders {
      rewrite /api/v1/orders(.*) /orders$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://orders_web:8003;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is to tell you that underscore (_) is not valid in a hostname. The most common place you see underscores in DNS is in server records, for example: `_protocol._tcp.example.com`, but they're not permitted in hostnames. You will need to rename the `products_web` service. Perhaps swap out underscores (_) for dashes (-), eg `products-web` etc.

Cheers!